# How to run visual studio pre-build events in windows and mac?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a pre-build event as follows:

```
ver
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
   REM some code
) else (
   REM some code
)
```

When running this on a mac os machine, ver command throws an error. How can I make this code run on both mac and windows?

Comment: Any luck on this, I need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I ended up solving the problem by writing two versions of the same script, one for windows, the other for bash/mac. Firstly, I added the following to my pre-build event in visual studio:

[image]
NOTE: The lack of an extension is on purpose.

Then I added two scripts, one called GenerateConfig.cmd for windows builds. The other script called GenerateConfig for mac builds. You'll also need to make sure the later script has the execute flag on it.